# Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

My Eclipse Version:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800
```

As I try to display something in the *Display* view or if I set a conditional breakpoint, I keep getting, e.g. for a `syso` in said view:

```
System.out.println("y u no work ???");
    Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements
```

Please don't mark this as a duplicate because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306195/why-do-i-keep-getting-evaluations-must-contain-either-an-expression-or-a-block) because it seems outdated.